# Image over Image using React/Javascript/NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, facebook-opengraph

I have 2 image. for example image 1 is a news thumbnail image. I want to add a promotional `PNG` banner on that image and create a output image. I want to make that output image as OG image. How I can do it?

Example Image 1:[image]
Example Image 2 (PNG): [image]

Output Image (Image 2 on Image 1): [image]

Comment: Unless facebook-opengraph has some API/method to do this (if so, it should be in their docs), I think you can only do this by using the HTML5 canvas. You can put these two in a canvas then making a 'screenshot' of that canvas.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of tackling this.

You can just put both images inside a container `div` with `position: relative` and have the background image fill the whole container and the overlay with `absolute` position placed at the bottom using `bottom: 0`.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.img-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img-bg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GROOE.jpg"  />
  <img class="img-overlay" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/31yEs.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: But I actually want to generate a output image. Which will be shown while I share this image on facebook or other platform.